# Send to -> Email a Link and AAM issues

Tags: 2010, alternate-access-mapping

Inherited the following:

```
Internal site: https://nameofsite Default Zone
External site: https://www.nameofsite.com Internet Zone
```

Navigate to external site, go to doc lib, select doc and attempt to send a link to the document using the send to menu and the correct URL appears in outlook email
ex: `https://www.nameofsite.com/sitename/doclib/nameofdoc.docx`

Navigate to internal site, go to same doc lib and select same doc and attempt to send a link and I do not get a matching URL.

I'm expecting `https://nameofsite/sitename/doclib/nameofdoc.docx`, instead I get `https://www.nameofsite.com/sitename/doclib/nameofdoc.docx`

I also have a TMG sitting in front of this as well. Personally, I've done AAM before (maybe with different naming conventions for host headers) but perhaps I have never noticed the send to menu before.

Where do I go for information on this?

I found the following link to help but wondered if I'm missing something. 
http://techblurt.com/2011/02/21/configuring-sharepoint-2010-alternate-access-mappings-and-my-sites-with-a-reverse-proxy-e-g-tmgisa/